# Four Spiraling Axes

Tags: code-golf, number-theory, grid

Take the numbers `0, 1, 2, 3, 4, ...` and arrange them in a clockwise spiral, starting downward, writing ***each digit*** in its own separate square.

Then, given one of four distinct and consistent ASCII characters (your choice) representing an axis, and an input integer `n`, output the first `n` terms of the sequence described by selecting squares along the corresponding axis.

For example, below is the arranged spiral up to partway through `29`. Suppose we use `u / d / l / r` for our four characters, representing `up / down / left / right`. Then, given `u` as input, we output `0, 5, 1, 4 ...` (the positive y-axis) up to the `n`th term. If we were instead given `l` as input, then it would be `0, 3, 1, 1 ...` up to the `n`th term.

```
  2---3---2---4---2---5---2
  |                       |
  2   1---3---1---4---1   6
  |   |               |   |
  2   2   4---5---6   5   2
  |   |   |       |   |   |
  1   1   3   0   7   1   7
  |   |   |   |   |   |   |
  2   1   2---1   8   6   2
  |   |           |   |   |
  0   1---0---1---9   1   8
  |                   |   |
  2---9---1---8---1---7   2
```

These are sequences on OEIS:

- http://oeis.org/A033953 for the positive x-axis
- http://oeis.org/A033988 for the positive y-axis
- http://oeis.org/A033989 for the negative x-axis
- http://oeis.org/A033990 for the negative y-axis

#### Examples

```
d 19
[0, 1, 1, 8, 3, 7, 6, 2, 1, 5, 1, 1, 6, 2, 2, 1, 3, 4, 0]

r 72
[0, 7, 1, 7, 4, 2, 8, 1, 1, 3, 1, 2, 0, 2, 3, 1, 3, 4, 6, 5, 5, 5, 7, 7, 8, 8, 9, 6, 8, 1, 1, 1, 2, 3, 1, 8, 0, 6, 1, 7, 0, 9, 2, 8, 4, 3, 2, 1, 1, 7, 2, 6, 2, 1, 3, 3, 5, 5, 3, 2, 2, 0, 4, 3, 2, 5, 4, 6, 5, 0, 5, 1]

u 1
[0]
```

### Rules

- If applicable, you can assume that the input/output will fit in your language's native Integer type.
- If you're using integers to represent the four axes, you can use negative integers without breaking the rules.
- The input and output can be given by [any convenient method](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/2447/42963).
- Either a full program or a function are acceptable. If a function, you can return the output rather than printing it.
- [Standard loopholes](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/1061/42963) are forbidden.
- This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf) so all usual golfing rules apply, and the shortest code (in bytes) wins.

Comment: Can we take negative integers for a couple directions?

Comment: @mbomb007 Sure, that would be OK.

Comment: Doesn't seem very practical, but can we return an integer that has the required digits except the leading zero (which would be implied anyway)?

Comment: @AdmBorkBork Basically I don't have such a solution in mind, just thought to ask. :)

Comment: A challenge is judged by the output. So if the zero isn't included, I'd think that would be wrong, because you'd count it wrong if the zero is excluded for string output. Python can output integers with leading zeros, so why not other languages.

Comment: @mbomb007 That's a good point. I'll reverse that ruling.

Comment: @EriktheOutgolfer Ruling reversed, see mbomb's point.

Comment: @Kitana Just figured out that the spiral is infinite and not limited to `n` numbers with wraparound.

Answer (score 5):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), <s>94</s> <s>89</s> <s>84</s> <s>83</s> <s>74</s> <s>72</s> 70 bytes

I used WolframAlpha and determined that an upper bound of 5<sup>n</sup> > 4n<sup>2</sup>+3n seems to be enough. It can be changed to 9<sup>n</sup> at no cost. For trying larger inputs, use `9*n*n` instead of `5**n` to avoid running out of memory.

```python
lambda d,n:["".join(map(str,range(5**n)))[x*(4*x+d)]for x in range(n)]
```

[**Try it online!**](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/qfZhvzPycxNyklUSFFJ88qWklJLys/M08jN7FAo7ikSKcoMS89VcNUSytPU1MzukJLw0SrQjtFMzYtv0ihQiEzTwGiIE8z9n9BUWZeiUKahrGOhSYXjKOLyjNE5hmiSRlq/gcA)

The inputs for directions are:

- 3: right
- -3: down
- -1: left
- 1: up

*Saved 14 bytes thanks to [Rod](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/47120/rod)*
*Saved 2 bytes thanks to [Jonathan Allan](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/53748/jonathan-allan)*

Answer (score 1):

## [MATL](https://github.com/lmendo/MATL), 32 bytes

```
tE1YLtn:qVXzw)3Lt3$)iX!w:qyfYm+)
```

Input is `n`, `a`, where `a` represents the axis as follows:

- `0`: left;
- `1`: up;
- `2`: right;
- `3`: down.

Output is a string.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syfn/v8TVMNKnJM@qMCyiqlzT2KfEWEUzM0Kx3KqwMi0yV1vz/39zIy4jAA) Or [verify all test cases](https://tio.run/##y00syfmf8L/E1TDSpyTPqjAsoqpc09inxFhFMzNCsdyqsDItMldb879LyH9DSy5jLnMjLiMuQy5DAA).

Answer (score 1):

will work for considerable n (like +1000)

## [JavaScript (Node.js)](https://nodejs.org), 104 bytes

```javascript
f=(d,n)=>--n?[...f(d,n),C(n*(4*n+d))]:[0]
C=(n,N=i=0)=>n>N?C(n-N,(p=10**i)*9*++i):+((p+--n/i|0)+"")[n%i]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TY/RioMwEEXf/YogLCQ6uhNttQppH/reHxChpeqSUqLUdlno9tvdONZFGEIyuffM3Mvp@9Sfb7q7B6at6mFoFK/ACLUNArMrwjBs6A17bjy@8oxfCVHmBZbOXnEDB6UVWrXZHnZWEhyAd0qi52nhZZ7va5H7nHe@pX3qXxS@64rCfOhyuNf9nSk20oHVP52FPB3Gzq3p22sdXtsv3vBnlQcxXPNAwiOXcMvjV1GVdp/w0mpzPCplne@7cF7OCOVu5YLMoEBgkmoDLAaWAkuARdRZz19TZ2pazQoYluKNubnWFIEzglJSpKSIiChnj6QO0hkvQAmNmSql2lBl9PVPkAvjhjjJPAtJPI1bkSaaLSndk8Xq8TwrniPhwrVerIRTfpvzHfThMpBjTttqOIJERDH8AQ)

#### Explanation

- 3: right
- -3: down (-3 is legit according to comments)
- -1: left
- 1: up
  (like @mbomb007)

C- nth digit of Champernowne's constant

### ________________________________________________________

Less efficient method (wont work for 1000+)

## [JavaScript (Node.js)](https://nodejs.org), 81 bytes

```javascript
f=(d,n)=>eval(`for(r=[],s=i=I="";I<n;)(s+=i++)[u=I*(4*I+d)]&&r.push(s[I++,u]),r`)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TU/bioMwEH33K4IPJaljMWq1tZt99xtEUBrbtYhKUstC6be7cdRFGEI4cy5zHuWr1FdV90@37WQ1jjdBJbRMfFevsqHFrVNUiSwHLWqRCtu@pF/thVHtiNpxWDaIdE/DfepIlu926tAP@ofqLHUcGHIGqmDjs9JPIshkC6T67Y332yLk2rW6a6pD093pjb5l4gbQJC6HIeGgkuCTydwccnh0dVsUQhjl8mfWx5pMqS1t4GfIPCAc5wQkABIDiYD4iBzX1YzMoOGEQLycLTbKNiIfrMkoRkaMDB8d@arhiHj4BhujCGPmiXFOOGdc/TvwjfCEPtGa5SF5jguR46@SGP/R5vRgzQrWSt5Gddyc5M39Tc@l6GAT4FNPA41/)

Answer (score 1):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly),  <s>19</s>  18 [bytes](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly/wiki/Code-page)

Uses the 5<sup>n</sup> trick from [mbomb007's Python answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/162578/53748)

```
4,0jḅɗ@€ị5*D€FʋṖ0;
```

A dyadic link taking `n` on the left and `d` and integer from: `[-3,-1,1,3]:[v,<,^,>]`

**[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/99Uy@VR05pjXW4Pd3c7mOgYZD3c0XpyugNQ7OHOaQbW////N/@vawwA)**

A 20 byte alternative that is both much faster and does not segfault for such small n is:

```
²×5D€ƲFị@4,0jḅɗ@€Ṗ0;
```

**[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8///QpsPTTV0eNa05tsnt4e5uBxMdg6yHO1pPTncAij3cOc3A@v///4YGpv8NAQQ)**

#### How?

```
4,0jḅɗ@€ị5*D€FʋṖ0; - Link: integer, n; integer, d
     ɗ@€           - last three links as a dyad with sw@pped arguments for €ach (of implicit range [1,n])
4,0                -   literal list [4,0]
   j               -   join with d = [4,d,0]
    ḅ              -   convert from base n = 4*n^2+d*n+0
        ị          - index into...
              ʋ    - last four links as a monad:
         5         -   five
          *        -   exponentiate = 5^n
           D€      -   decimal list of each (in implicit range [1,5^n])
            F      -   flatten into a single list of the digits
               Ṗ   - pop (drop the final element)
                0; - prepend a zero
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Stax](https://github.com/tomtheisen/stax), 13 [bytes](https://github.com/tomtheisen/stax/blob/master/docs/packed.md#packed-stax)

```
â╞ê←τ"(]]⌐┘?N
```

[Run and debug it](https://staxlang.xyz/#p=83c6881be722285d5da9d93f4e&i=3+1%0A7+19%0A1+72&m=2)

It takes input with the direction, followed by the count.  Right, up, left, and down are `1`, `3`, `5`, and `7` respectively.  It takes a full minute to run the three provided test cases.